# Who has strong reference to UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate?

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit

When you write your own transition controller delegate, you instantiate an instance and assign it to the VC that is being presented. But that property, `transitioningDelegate` is `weak`. So you can't stop there; you have to assign it to a strong property to keep it in memory until the presented VC is dismissed.

The question is, who holds the strong reference to this object? Is it the

1. *presented* VC? or,
2. *presenting* VC?

Why?

Comment: which object you are pointing?

Comment: What do you mean, “which object”?